# How to prove that $\frac{1}{1-z}=\prod_{n=0}^\infty (1+z^{2^n})$?

Tags: complex-analysis, infinite-product, meromorphic-functions

A simple pole can be written as $\displaystyle{\frac{c}{c-z}=\prod_{n=1}^\infty e^{\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{z}{c}\right)^n}}$. How does one show that when $c=1$, $\displaystyle{\frac{1}{1-z}=\prod_{n=0}^\infty (1+z^{2^n})}$?

Comment: Write each natural number in base $2$.

Comment: Multiply both sides by $1-z$!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

$$\dfrac{1-z^{2^{n+1}}}{1-z}=\prod_{r=0}^n(1+z^{2^r})$$ for $z\ne1$

Now if $|z|<1,$  $$\lim_{r\to\infty}z^r=0$$

Here $r=?$

Comment: But now I want to know how you arrived at your first expression.

Comment: @Master Drifter note that $a^m-b^m = (a-b)(a^{m-1} + a^{m-2} b + a^{m-3} b^2 + \cdots + b^{m-1}).$ In this case $m = 2^{n+1}$ which is even. Can you get my hint?

Comment: Note that if we take $m=4$ then $a^4 -b^4 = (a-b) ( a^3 + a^2 b + ab^2 + b^3).$ Then observe that $$a^3 + a^2 b + ab^2 + b^3 = a^2 (a+b) + b^2 (a+b) = (a+b)(a^2+ b^2).$$ So $$\frac {1-z^{2^2}} {1-z} = (1+z) (1+z^2) = \prod_{r=0}^{1} (1+z^{2^r}).$$

Comment: The last expression is valid only for $z \neq 1.$

Comment: $$(a+b)(a-b)=?$$ $$(a^2-b^2)(a^2+b^2(=?$$ and so on.  The condition $z\ne1$ is already there